# What's the difference style of writing in .net's MVC2,MVC3 and Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

If anybody has written application in .net's MVC2 and MVC3, there is a change of syntax in writing a code like

```
<%= %>
```

has been replaced by

```
<%: %>
```

or

```
@
```

so this mean that:

```
<%= %> == <%: %>  OR <%= %> == @
```

are equals?

Comment: I think that you are talking about Razor Syntax, it's a more concise way of embedding code in the view.  [Razor Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: yes, I am starting to write my application in MVC3 using razor so just want to clear some doubts ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= %>
```

Writes out the string exactly as is.

```
<%: %>
```

Html Encodes the string and then writes it out.

```
@
```

Html Encodes the string and then writes it out if you're using the Razor view engine.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there any difference in writing syntax between MVC2 and MVC3? because once I tried using this <%: %> in MVC2 application and it gave me an error

Comment: @dvlpr I'm a little confused about when that was added. [This link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) says it was added with ASP.Net 4 in MVC 2, but I was under the impression it came with MVC 3. I have MVC 3 installed, so you may have the best chance at testing.

Comment: thanks again, my application is using .Net 3.5, that's why it gave me an error not because of MVC3